# why does this for loop returns null?

Tags: php, for-loop

```
<?  
for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {


    $b=urlencode($cl[1][$i]);
    $ara = array("http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/", "http%3A%2F%2Fanonymouse.org%2Fcgi-bin%2Fanon-www.cgi%2F");
    $degis   = array("", "");
    $t = str_replace($ara, $degis, $b);
    $c="$t";
    $base64=base64_encode($t);


    $y=urldecode($t);
    $u=base64_encode($y);
    $qwe = "http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/$y";
    $ewq = "h.php?y=$u";
    $bul = ($qwe);
    $degistir = ($ewq);
    $a =str_replace($bul, $degistir, $ic);
}
?>
```

when i put `$cl[1][0], $cl[1][1], $cl[1][2]` works successfull but when i put `$i` its returning null. why is this happening?

**I'm trying to change EACH url to base64 codes that I received from remote url with preg_match_all **

Comment: What are you doing with all the return values? As it stands, $base64 is being overwritten in each loop.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do with this? Because it looks overly complicated. Is your goal to get rid of the `http://` prefix at the beginning, or at some other point in the string? For the former, there are better methods

Comment: im getting urls from remote source url with preg_match_all and replacing them with base64 -_-

Comment: same code is working for me. Also $c1 's second index length must be greater than equal to 10.

Comment: what is $ic in last line of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that `$c1[1]` has 10 elements? (From `$c1[1][0]` to `$c1[1][9]` there are **10** elements, **not 9**.

Maybe you are getting `null` for the last one `$c1[1][9]`. Try to do a `var_dump($c1[1])` to check that it contains all the elements that you expect.

Update:

Change the this line

```
for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {
```

into this

```
for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++) {
```

Comment: var_dump($cl[1]) returns array(9) is this the problem?

Comment: Yes. Your array contains 9 elements, but you are iterating over 10 elements,  hence 1 is null. See my updated response.

Comment: when i use  for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) = $c1[1][8], ($i=0; $i<9; $i++) = $c1[1][8] not all changing only one.